# Is it possible to identify all the feature layer inside of other layer?

Tags: openlayers

Let's say I have two layers namely: layer1 and layer 2.

[image: Layers]

Is it possible to get all the feature layers inside the other layer? 
In the example returns all the grays inside the red box.

Comment: Will you always be interested in polygons inside a rectangle, or could it be polygons inside polygons.

Comment: Polygons inside the other polygons...Both polygons are not on the same layer.

Comment: OK, in that case, I have posted an answer for polygon/polygon intersection from two different vector layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [intersects function](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Geometry/LineString.js) defined for LineStrings, and so any geometry can call this function to determine intersection with another geometry  -- in the case of Polygons, it will simply be called for each combination of their respective linestrings. For a point/polygon intersection, this simply becomes contains.

So, to find any intersections between two different vector layers, (and assuming that your layer1 and layer2 refer to the vector layers and not the features in them), you can do,

```
var features1 = layer1.features;
var features2 = layer2.features;

for (var i=0; i < features1.length-1; i++){
   var feature1 = features1[i];
   for (var j=0; j < features2.length-1; j++){
       var feature2 = features2[j];
       if (feature1.geometry.intersects(feature2.geometry)){
            console.log("vector features 1 " + i + " intersects vector features 2 " + j;
       }
   }
}
```

Obviously, you could also write the test simply as,

```
for (var i=0; i < features1.length-1; i++){
   for (var j=0; j < features2.length-1; j++){
        if(feature1.feature[i].geometry.intersects(feature2.feature[j].geometry)){
              //do something
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does it possible using OpenLayers API v3.1? if it is possible could you please help me, because i am facing same issue with API v3.1?